# Border wont remove in html table

Tags: html, html-table, border

I've got a **HTML table** with several cells inside, the `border=0` property is set yet the border does not go away, what am I doing wrong?

```
<table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">    
        <tr>
          <td>
            <br><br>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Try this [How to completely remove borders from html table][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684144/how-to-completely-remove-borders-from-html-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first cell spacing to 0

So here's the code:

```
<table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"     
bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>

<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<tr>
<td><br>
<br></td>
</tr>


</table>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
```