# Problem with the background color of the <tr>

Tags: html, css

I have made a table where I display data that is structuredThe problem is that I insert a background color but this does it for all sections. The problem is that I would like to be able to display the three characteristics as this image shows.
[THE PROJECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ8ra.png)

But I get this:
[MY RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsddx.png)

HTML CODE:

```
<?php
                $sql = "SELECT enc_id, enc_cmd_num, enc_paye, enc_prepared, enc_ext_ref, enc_heure_fab_deb, enc_type, enc_heure_fab_fin, Client.cli_civilite,Client.cli_nom, Client.cli_prenom FROM Client RIGHT JOIN encaissement ON Client.cli_id = encaissement.enc_client WHERE enc_etat<>4 AND enc_date= '20230104' AND ((DATEDIFF(n,enc_heure_fab_fin, getDate()) < 3 AND enc_prepared <> 0) OR enc_prepared = 0) AND enc_emporte <> 1 ORDER BY encaissement.enc_heure_fab_deb ASC";
 
                $results = odbc_exec( $conn, $sql );
            ?>
            <table>
            <?php
                while( $row = odbc_fetch_array( $results ) )
                {
                    printf('<tr>');
 
                    if ( $row["enc_ext_ref"] != '')
                                    {
                                        $num_cmd = $row["enc_ext_ref"];
                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        $num_cmd =$row["enc_cmd_num"];
                                    }
 
                     
                    if ($row['enc_paye'] = 0)
                    {
                        $etat_cmd='<span class="PRETE">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspATTENTE REGLEMENT&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span></br>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        switch( $row['enc_prepared'] )
                        {
                            case 0: $etat_cmd='<span class="ENPREPA">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspEN PREPARATION&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span>'; break;
 
                            case 1: $etat_cmd='<span class="PRETE">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspCOMMANDE PRETE&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span></br>'; break;
                        }
                    }
 
                    switch( $row['enc_type'] )
                    {
                        case 0: $commande='<span class="EMPORTER">&nbsp&nbsp<img src="img/emporter.png" id="EMP"></img></span>&nbsp'; break;
 
                        case 1: $commande='<span class="LIVRAISON">&nbsp&nbsp<img src="img/livreur.png" id="LIV"></img></span>&nbsp</br>'; break;
 
                        case 2: $commande='<span class="SURPLACE">&nbsp&nbsp<img src="img/table.png" id="TABLE"></img></span>&nbsp</br>'; break;
                    }
                    printf('<td>%s</td>',$row["enc_cmd_num"]);
                    printf('<td>%s</td>',$etat_cmd);
                    printf('<td>%s</td>',$commande);
               
                }
            ?>
            </table>
 
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
/*FONTS*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap');
 
 
 
.ENPREPA{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    color: #FF8C01;
}
 
.PRETE{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    color:#05750D;
    animation-duration: .8s;
    animation-name: clignoter;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    transition: none;
}
 
@keyframes clignoter {
  0%   { color:#000000; }
  40%   {color:#F1A200; }
  100% { opacity:#000000; }
}
 
 
li{
  color: #EB0000;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
 
 
}
 
 
.ATTENTE{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
 
}
 
.PAYE{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #11C306;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
}
 
#time{
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
 
 
 
table{
    float: left;
}
 
tr{
    color: red;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-weight: bold;
}
 
.SURPLACE{
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
}
 
#TABLE{
width : 100px;
height : 70px;
}
 
td{
    background-color: #181818;
    border-radius: 13px;
}
 
#EMP{
width : 70px;
height : 70px;
}
 
#LIV{
width : 70px;
height : 70px;
}
```

Comment: probable solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684144/how-to-completely-remove-borders-from-html-table

Comment: to make sure I understand correctly, you want the text in the other < tr> to also be in red like the one on the left?

Comment: @Rimon no basically I just want there to be no space between each section so it forms a single block

Answer (score -1):

If you add this to your CSS it should remove all spacing between the cells

```
tr,
th,
td {
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: I just tested and it doesn't work, there is still a separation between the sections

Comment: can you add the generated html instead in addition to the PHP code to your question? You can load the page, inspect, copy the html and add it here, it will help with the debugging